# Does MPXJ support MPP files of 2013 version?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, ms-project, mpxj

Does MPXJ support reading MPP files of 2013 version? If so, which version of MPXJ to be considered for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

MPXJ supports MPP files written by Microsoft Project 2013. I would always recommend using the latest version of MPXJ to benefit from fixes and functionality improvements.

Comment: Thanks. Will try and revert in case of any issues.

Comment: @Jon Iles I really liked MPXJ library, found it very very useful and easy. Thanks for writing and maintaining the library.